# Converting a sql server query to sqlite "Convert(date, getdate())"

Tags: c#, xamarin, sqlite, sql-server-2012

I am working on a xamarin android project and trying to convert a sql server  query to sqlite
I have a Sql Server script that uses the date :

```
"Convert(date, getdate())"
```

what would be the equivalent for a sqlite db3 database query as this would throw an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this returns only the date portion of the current datetime

```
Convert(date, getdate())
```

the equivalent in sqlite would be

```
SELECT date('now');
```

Comment: One more question Jason what about a query in SQL Server that is 'where dCreationDate = GETDATE()'?

Comment: select datetime('now')

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is `DATETIME('now')`.